# pip install fails with failed to parse error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, travis-ci

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse:
```

I am using below command for installation
`python3.7 -m pip install --user xxx-scanner`

I tried this command on ubuntu vm.This command works in my vm but fails from travis setup

`ubuntu dist: xenial`

Comment: What is "xxx-scanner"? There seems to be no such package in [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=xxx-scanner).

Comment: xxx is not relevant here. had it been issue with the pkg name, pip would have thrown diff error.I have found the related issue. posting below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the issue 
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6775

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6775) provided by @ambikanair if you get an error like:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse:

you likely need to escape characters like `@` or `%` in the URL in your pip configuration file (e.g. `~/.pip/pip.conf`), so instead of:

```
user@domain.com
```

do:

```
user%40domain.com
```

This is a requirement since pip 19.2, caused by urrlib3 library introducing changes to [URL parsing](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/1647) (see [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1640)).